# How to join the transactions to get the data after the update query execution in spring data jpa?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my case i have to update the record and in the different transaction im selecting the updated record in this case my result set is zero, because its not yet committed in the db.

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public void updateTables(String name, Long id) {
        
        Query vehDefectQuery = entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("UPDATE STUDENT SET DEPT= ? WHERE ID=?");
        vehDefectQuery = vehDefectQuery.setParameter(1, name).setParameter(2, id);
        vehDefectQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager2")
public void selectTheUpdated(String dept ) {
        
        Query selectQuery= entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM STUDENT  WHERE DEPT=?");
        selectQuery= selectQuery.setParameter(1, dept);
        selectQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

In the select transaction im not getting the results

Comment: You can't join two transactions. You have to commit the first transaction, depending on isolation levels before the second one starts.

Comment: when i try to commit the update transaction entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); throws an error Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You cannot use `executeYpdate` for a select query.

Comment: Sorry its  selectQuery.getResultList()